# PHP syntax breaking the image tag

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue with my live site that works fine on a dev site (on a different host).

Essentially, it's brining in the image incorrectly and adding characters at the end... example:
    https://www.idealhomeloans.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/refinance-1.jpg/%3E%20%3Cimg%20src=

it should just be: https://www.idealhomeloans.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/refinance-1.jpg

This is the php code I'm using to bring the image in...

```
        <?php if( $image ): ?>


            <?php 
            echo '<img class="'. $imagealigned.'"     src="';the_sub_field('image');
        echo '/>';

             ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

  <?php $image  = get_sub_field('image');
//Checking if anything exists for the image field
if ($image) { ?>
<?php echo '<img src="';// display a sub field value
    the_sub_field('image');
    echo '/>';
    ?>
 <?php } //if there is nothing for image then display
else { ?>
<?php } 
?>
```

Can someone who knows PHP well take a look and see if there's something that would render the image tag to come in correctly?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `src="';the_sub_field('image');` is likely supposed to have a `.` to concatenate before the call to `the_sub_field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put values into variables.

```
<?php if ($image): ?>
    <img src="<?= $src; ?>" class="<?= $class; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is easier to keep the formats and tags of the html, and you could become less confused. Plus I think it is much cleaner.

Comment: Yeah I would like to clean up the syntax if possible... the echo stuff seems weird to me... but I get confused because of the if (image) stuff... when I try it that way it breaks the page.

Comment: If <?= $variable; ?> is weird to you, then use <?php echo $variable; ?> instead.

Comment: If you're confused by the if ($image) - you are using it in your sample in the opening post. But for me the if ($a): then endif; is more readable when it is used in html. In pure php files the braces are cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to this: 
    <?php if ($image): ?>
    <img src="<?= $image; ?>" class="<?= $imagealigned; ?>" />
   <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you actually LOOKED at the html you're generating, you'd see that you're generating BAD html:

```
echo '<img class="'. $imagealigned.'"     src="';the_sub_field('image');
                                              ^---start HTML attribute
echo '/>';
      ^----never end the attribute
```

So you're building

```
<img .... src="kittens.jpg>
```

and around and around the error merrygoround you go...

Comment: look at my comment also. They aren't concatenating. So unless `the_sub_field` is echo'ing out it is more like `<img ... src="/>`.

Comment: it's wordpuke (that is NOT a typo...). most functions do direct output, and only the `get_whatever` return their data instead.

Comment: wow, lame. Thankfully never really did any WP dev other than a simple install once or twice for friends.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I never noticed the missing " in the tag...<IMG src="blah.jpg"/>... sorry I'm not a true expert in php (can get around enough), can you guys elaborate on what you mean by not concatenating?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a semicolon (;) instead of a point (.) to concatenate the_sub_field